# How do I beat "Mr. T is hanging around"?

Tags: crayon-physics-deluxe

[image]

Try as I might, I just *cannot* get "Mr. T" to swing far enough to let my little ball pass under.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spoilers, but that goes without saying on a question like this.

Place a pin on one side of the T and hang a large weight off of it.  Click on the ball to kick it right.

[image]

The elegant/old-school solution can be had by a single thing that locks over the top of the T and has an extension that will smack the ball when it falls and lifts the gate.  It's a pain in the ass, only did it once and didn't SS it :(

Comment: Ah I forgot I could draw pins!

Answer (score -3):

You could try to place the bat in the right direction in order to hit the ball hard enough.